# Regex.Split string on each literal (included in result)

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

```
string s = "123wWdf4d556e";
```

after splitting result should be:

```
"123", "w", "W", "d", "f", "4", "d", "556", "e"
```

The logic is: split to each integer number, and single char.

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work. An explanation would be nice, so I can understand why it didn't work. :)

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, "\w+(?=[a-zA-Z]");
```

**Edit:** edited the above result.

Comment: Was the `f` voluntarily omitted?

Comment: yes, f was omitted by mistake, sorry. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a look-*behind*:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, "(?<=[a-zA-Z])");
```

Yours doesn't work because you are trying to split on word characters, and in the course of the split such characters will be removed from the result. Think about it like this:  When you split a CSV-string on a comma, are the commas preserved in the result? The same kind of thing is happening in your attempt.

Using an assertion, like you were trying and what I am displaying, works because it's akin to splitting on the void next to the character you are seeking. This is because assertions are "zero-width"--they don't consume anything. So the pattern above basically says, "split on the void that comes after an alphabetic character."

Per you edit, you can use the same concept, but expand on it a tad:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])");
```

You use alternation ( `|` ) to set up the variants of what you want to split on:  integer followed by a letter ( `(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])` ); letter followed by an integer ( `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)` ); any two consecutive letters ( `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])` ). Each variant uses assertions to split on the voids between the target characters. Using a combination of lookbehind and lookahead permits you to split on this exact void.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I completely asked the question wrong, probably due to being lost. The result I require is that numbers and chars must be split also. I appologize, I have updated the question to correct the result.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, I need to study your solution now, which is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This works for a *match*, not a *split*.

The following regex will work if you use the 'ignore case' flag (i).

```
\d*[a-z]
```

**Explanation**

Your regex captured all words greedily up to when it was followed by a letter. It did not capture the letter since you used a lookahead.

My regex captures all digits (if any) and the first letter following the digit. You can see it in action on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5Cd%2a%5Ba-z%5D&flags=i&str=123wWdf4d556e). Note that the `f` is captured, which you omitted from you expected result. I assume this was a mistake.